# In which class should wrapped EF entities be saved?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I have a WPF application which is written with an implementation of MVVM. There's no extra framework for the MVVM pattern.

My entities from EF db first are wrapped in their own viewmodels and I have a modelcontroller to load them into their viewmodels from a 'window' viewmodel.

Example of an entity viewmodel:

```
public class PurchaseOrderViewModel : ViewModels.ViewModelBase
{
    private someType _prop;
    public someType Prop 
    {
        get
        {
            return _prop;
        }
        set 
        {
            _prop = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // ... 
    // Other Properties
    // ... 

    public PurchaseOrderViewModel() {
        // default constructor for LINQ
    }
    public PurchaseOrderViewModel(purchaseorder entity)
    {
        // load values from entity in properties
    }
}
```

Example of a window viewmodel:

```
public class MainViewModel: ViewModels.ViewModelBase
{
    private IModelController modelController = new ModelController();

    private List<PurchaseOrderViewModel> _poList;
    public List<PurchaseOrderViewModel> POList
    {
        get
        {
            return _poList;
        }
        set 
        {
            _poList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // ... 
    // Other Properties
    // ... 

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        POList = modelController.GetPurchaseOrders();
    }
}
```

Example of ModelController:

```
public class ModelController : IModelController
{
    public List<PurchaseOrderViewModel> GetPurchaseOrders() 
    {
        using (var model = new DBContext())
        {
            return model.purchaseorders
                        .Select(new PurchaseOrderViewModel { /* assign properties */ })
                        .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Where am I supposed to save this wrapped viewmodel (PurchaseOrderViewModel) once the user is done editing it? As I see it, there are 2 options:

1. Create a save function in each viewmodel that points back to the modelController, but this feels like an inappropriate approach.
2. Create a save function in the modelcontroller and pass the viewmodel as an argument

It's most likely that I'm missing something in the MVVM pattern, but please point me in the right direction. Thank you!

**EDIT**: I excluded the view (MainView) from the info provided, but this view binds directly to the properties exposed by MainViewModel.

Comment: Option 1 comes closest, not inappropriate.  But you're not using MVVM to the fullest. You ought to base VMs on the Views (uses cases), not on your model.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are saying then I guess I already do that. My MainView binds directly to the properties of the MainViewModel. I didn't include that info because I thought it was irrelevant to the question.

Comment: No, I meant that the ViewModels shouldn't follow the Models classes too closely. Their names should come from screens you design.

Comment: Something along the lines of "PurchaseOrderRowData" if it's supposed to viewed in a datagrid?

Comment: Yes, but on what View is that  DataGrid ?

Comment: On the MainView in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, I problably wouldn't name it `ModelController` as that's slightly confusing makes people think you are speaking MVC.  Instead, if you call it *xxxx*`Service` (e.g. `PurchaseOrdersService`) it makes more sense and it no longer feels *"inappropriate"* because having a **VM** delegate the actual work is what many users of IoC do.  Plus it keeps your **VM** clean.

---

**NOTE**:  By *"service"* I don't necessarily mean that your **VM** will be calling a WCF service directly (nor should you).  Service is just a means to achieve something in an abstract and encapsulated way on behalf of clients. Examples include:

1. saving information to a DB
2. getting the current log mechanism
3. They can even be facades whereby they create a WCF client proxy and call a remote service on your behalf without you having to know the details.

---

So a typical flow is:

Command >> **View** code behind >> **VM** >> Service

The reason I include the view's code behind is that typically this is where you:

1. Catch exceptions
2. The starting point of `async/await` for asynchonous calls to your **VM** and service

Now when you pass context fromt the VM back to the service, there is no rule on what exactly you pass however I see no reason to pass **VM** to the service because that contains information the service doesn't care about.

Just pass the **M** which your **VM** should have bound to in the first place and continued to update via binding.

Comment: In this case I am using Entity Framework as my model. Does this mean that I need to continuously update that specific entity when my viewmodel its exposed properties change and give this entity back to the service layer when saving back to the database? My apologies if this sounds like a dumb question. Do you know where I could find an example of this implementation?

Comment: @MichelMichels Generally not, if its a datagrid you save all changes when moving to the next row.  Otherwise if its a details view, when a change is made to the **V**, databinding immediately informs the **VM**.  Your **VM** should have a `Modified` flag that when true either enables a **Save** button (if you have one) in your **V** that when clicked executes your `Save` command.  Alternatively, you can intercept your view closing event and just prior check to see if changes were made and ask the user do they wish to save.

Comment: @MichelMichels As for an example I should have given you enough to go on but if not, just Google _"WPF MVVM IoC services"_